# Animating Custom Buttons Stuck in End Point

Tags: ios, animation, button

**EDITED Question:**

So i have this code for some custom buttons (clouds) that move from right to left and animate when they are tapped.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Move UIView

    cloudAnimate.center = CGPointMake(400.0, 90.0);
    cloudAnimate1.center = CGPointMake(400.0, 150.0);
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                          delay:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         cloudAnimate.center = CGPointMake(100.0, 90.0);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:8.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         cloudAnimate1.center = CGPointMake(100.0, 150.0);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];


}
```

The code does what i want so am happy there but if that View is on and you exit the app and re enter to that view the clouds are stuck at the end point. I have to leave the view and come back in to it to get them to start again.

Is there a way that when you exit the view the clouds pause where they are and when you go back in they are where they were and continue to animate as normal?

Comment: why you call super's viewDidLoad in viewDidAppear? It doesn't make sense and it cause undesired behaviour

Comment: ok thanks, I am learning so hadn't noticed that - however it has not resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your problem?

```
- (void)**viewDidAppear**:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super **viewDidLoad**];
```

Comment: Hi James, I have tried removing [super viewDidLoad] and it didn't fix the issue - am i missing something?

Comment: I wouldn't remove it, I'd try replacing it with `[super viewDidAppear];`

Comment: I get an error when I put that in that says: 'No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'viewDidAppear'

Comment: It takes the animated parameter too: `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`

Comment: Yea sorry, just tried that too and has the same effects, if the clouds are half way across the screen and i press the home button, when i go back in the clouds are there but they disappear within half a second and never come back, I have even tried changing coordinates to see if they go back to their start position but this isn't the case. Do I need to call a viewDidDisappear or something to pause the animating clouds?

Answer (score 0):

Move the lines

```
cloudAnimate.center = CGPointMake(400.0, 90.0);
cloudAnimate1.center = CGPointMake(400.0, 150.0);
```

into `viewWillAppear:`. This way the buttons` positions will be reset every time you're reopening the app.

Comment: Hi BlackRider, Ok I've tried that and a) it didn't work. b) there is a slight delay when the view loads for the first time moving the buttons to the start positions. Isn't there a way that when you exit the view the clouds pause where they are and when you go back in they are where they were and continue to animate as normal?